# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll vb .net

Tags: vb.net, exception, unhandled

I'm new in vb .net programming, I've been encountering the following error when I'm trying to connect my form button to MySql database that:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll Additional information: Keyword not supported.

I have been working to sort this error but I didn't succeed. Please see my code for the class below:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connect As New MySqlConnection
        Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password; Database=sist"
        connect.ConnectionString = connecto
        Try
            connect.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection string. According to [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) it should look like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

so in your case:

```
Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; Uid=root; Pwd=yourPassword; Database=sist"
```